# Google OAuth consent screen verification rejected because authorized domains include apple.com

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

My IOS app (React Native) uses OAuth to login with google. To do this, I needed to create a OAuth 2.0 Client ID with type iOS. This requires I put apple.com in the authorized domains section of my OAuth consent screen. My login flow works perfectly, but google won't verify my app because it says:

*Your project has multiple domains which appear unrelated to the application currently under review: apple.com*

In summary, I can't get a client ID without using apple.com, and I cant get verified while using apple.com. Seems like a strange situation, and I cant seem to get ahold of anyone at google to help explain it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Tried:
Submitting my app for verification with Google.

Expected:
To be approved.

Actual Result:
App rejected citing the domain apple.com is unrelated to my application.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Thought i'd post the answer here incase its helpful for anyone.

Under authorized domains I was getting "missing domain: apple.com". I thought this was because I had created an OAuth client id with type IOS. It was actually happening because on my OAuth consent screen I had used the apple standard terms of service link:
[image: screenshot of consent screen]

Replacing this with a terms of service link on my website got it working!